# Save/loading in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Now i realize this question gets asked a lot and i assure you i have done a lot of searching on the subject, have tried some scripts and tried the serializer from unity's asset store. but i just can't find what i need.

the next level only unlocks after beating the previous one so it needs to remember which levels have been beaten/unlocked and when you load you can pick any of the unlocked levels also the highest score on each level needs to be remember and only be replaced if a new score is higher, lower scores don't need to be saved.

what i kept finding on google was how to save all objects and stuff that happened in the level but i don't need in-level saving, my levels are really short and ment to be played in 1 go.

EDIT:
this is the script where i'd add 1 to levelIndex after the player beats the level
and my goal is after the player presses load in the startmenu, a new menu pops up and the player will be able to choose from all the unlocked levels and after choosing, the level will load.

(what i currently have regarding this issue is on the // lines)

```
#pragma strict
var normalParticle : ParticleSystem;
var teleportParticle : ParticleSystem;
var teleportSound : AudioClip;
var ignoreListenerPause: boolean;
// var levelIndex : int;
function Start() {
    teleportParticle.Stop();
}

function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player"){
        teleportParticle.Play();
        normalParticle.Stop();
        for (var o : GameObject in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Virus"))
        {
            var comp : Component = o.GetComponent(ChaseScript);
            if (comp != null)
            {
                comp.active = false;
            }
        }
        yield WaitForSeconds (0.5);
        audio.ignoreListenerPause = true;
        audio.PlayOneShot(teleportSound);
        yield WaitForSeconds (3.9);
        //levelIndex++;
        //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Last_Level", levelIndex);
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel+1);
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit(other : Collider)
{

    teleportParticle.Stop();
    normalParticle.Play();

}
```

i found a tutorial earlier explaining how to achieve what i wanted but it's not effective for a game with a lot of levels, he uses a script per level completed and uses if's for every single level and my game would have around 50 so i would prefer a better/cleaner way here is the video: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-level-unlocking-system-using-playerprefs.146955/. u can see his scripts at 10:10 and 14:14.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems json might be overkill for your problem, i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is simple enough, like just one or two variables when skip to step 3.

1. Create class to hold your data about progression
2. Serialize the class with json to get a string
3. Store the data in PlayerPrefs

Save

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Last_Level", levelIndex);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Load

```
int levelIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Last_Level", 0);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i've been trying this for the last hour to get that to work but i think json is too complicated for me right now i'm already having issues using PlayerPrefs which should be a lot easier than json from what i've read online. Also i'm currenty working in unityscript because i find it easier than c# and almost anything i could find about json examples were in c#

since i won't have enough characters in this comment i will edit my question with more details, if you could provide me with examples i think i will be able to understand it a lot easier :) thanks in advance